# In the US, what is the process for filing a DROTAM?

Tags: airspace, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

For drone pilots in the US, what is the process for filing a DROTAM?

Comment: This might be a better fit on [drones.se]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Drones.SE.

Comment: I posted here because increasingly drones are used in commercial applications, and the issuance of DROTAMS while perhaps not of substantial interest to airliners and military jet jocks, are relevant to other sectors of aviation.  Local medvac guys brief on them daily.  Pipeline patrol and utility operator dispatchers are aware of them.  None of the three local ag operators look at them, but now that they are aware of them, they plan on briefing them daily.  It seems to be relevant to NAS and in general aviation safety, hence the posting.

Comment: This question seems appropriate both for aviation and drones/models. But it's not expected you ask "how to do..." without explaining your own attempt to file a Drotam and what difficulty you encountered, if any. To me the dedicated site which link was provided is self-sufficient a priori.